# In 5-card stud does 2 kings beat 2 jacks and 2 threes?

Tags: odds

1. King of Diamonds, King of hearts, 3 of diamonds, 5 of diamonds and a Queen of hearts in one hand. The other player has Jack of spades,Jack of diamonds, 3 of clubs, 3 of hearts and a 6 of hearts. Which hand wins?

Answer (score 0):

KKQ53 = one pair of kings + Q53 kicker.

JJ336 = two pair + 6 kicker.

Two pair > one pair. Two pair wins.